# andrioad studio telling "expecting member declaration" when i type the word "webview"

Tags: android, android-webview, kotlin-android-extensions

andrioad studio telling "expecting member declaration" when i type the word "webview" on mainactivity.kt  am done with the main_activity.xml part and it was fine.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    public WebView webView;

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Comment: you are mixing Java and Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin, you first type name of the variable and then it's type.

```
public var webView: WebView? = null
```